# Confusing behaviour when looping through a 2-dimensional array (foreach)

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array, foreach

Morning all,

I'm sure this may be a lack of fully understanding how 2-dimensional array access works in PowerShell but I'm experiencing some odd behaviour:

Here is my code:

```
$testarray = @( ("a",1),("b",2)) 

echo $testarray[0]
echo "____________"

foreach ($test in $testarray)
{

    echo $test[0]

}
```

Now when I run this I expect both echos to produce A1 and I've setup a 2D array where element 0 is made up of 2 values A and 1. But when I loop through this I don't get  the same results.

Does foreach treat these arrays differently? In theory I should be able to access the value 1 by going `$test[0][1]`.

Is this expected behaviour? I'm inclined to think I don't fully understand what foreach is doing with the array.

The reason I am using a 2D array is that I'd like to store a FileObject in the first element and then a friendly name in the second, e.g:

```
$SLFile = (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Filter "file1_*.csv" | sort LastWriteTime -Descending)[0]
$SOHFile = (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Filter "file2_*.csv" | sort LastWriteTime -Descending)[0]

#Add to an array
$fileArray = @(  ($SLFile,"FriendlyFile1Name"), ($SOHFile, "FriendlyFile2Name")  )
```

When I did this I kept getting this behaviour so decided to do some testing (but haven't really made any progress hence why I'm now here :))

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,
Ben

Comment: Are you sure you want a multi-dimensional array and not a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) in the first place?

Comment: Hi alroc, I thought about that tried it but preferred the idea of an array (sort of like a 'matrix table')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run it and get:

```
a
1
____________
a
b
```

And yes, this is expected behaviour. In the first case you are saying: "Show me what is in my multidimensional array at the first index". Here it finds the array ("a",1) and returns that. In the second case you are saying: "Iterate through my multidimensional array and show what is at the first index in either". That gives you a,b.

You are not able to say `$test[0][1]` because $test is a loop variable containing a one-dimensional array. You can, however, say `$testarray[0][1]` to access the 1.

Please be aware that you have created a jagged array here, not necessarily a matrix.

Comment: Ah right, ok ... so I'd be better served using a for..loop and iterating through the primary array (e.g: $testarray[$counter][0] or [1]) 

Jagged array? Like an array within an array? Many thanks Palle Due

Comment: @user792587: A true multidimensional array is a matrix, like 5x8 or 4x3. In a jagged array the "rows" aren't necessarily equally long. You can have (1,2,3),(4,5),(6).

Comment: PowerShell does support indexing into multi-dimensional arrays but there is no syntax for creating one. Instead you have to do `$a = [array]::CreateInstance([object], 3,2)`. Indexing is then `$a[1,1]`. Notice that this is the same syntax as an array slice. PowerShell looks at the object being indexed and if it's a multi-dimensional array, it does indexing instead of slicing. Also `foreach` enumerates over all of the individual items in the array, not just the rows. So, while we do support multi-dimensional arrays, you're almost always better off with jagged arrays (arrays of arrays).